# Segmentation fault during 'import scipy' and 'import numpy'

Tags: python, numpy, osx-mavericks

I want to use theano on my MacOS 10.9 Maverick. It used to work fine on 10.8 Lion. But there are some issues with 10.9.

Specifically, when I typed 'import numpy' or 'import scipy', it crashed and the error message is 'Segmentation fault: 11'

Any idea how I can solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you install numpy, scipy, and theano by using `pip` to build them locally? If not, then how _did_ you install them? Also, did you install them for the Python 2.7 that Apple gave you as part of the OS, or for a different Python installation (a different 2.7, or a completely different version)?

Comment: Anyway, whatever the specifics, there's a good chance that the answer will be to reinstall theano and all of its requirements. You often need to do this after an OS major version upgrade. Between 10.7 and 10.8, because Apple didn't change their built-in Python, many people got away with not updating their packages, but in 10.9 Apple's has updated their built-in Python, so that won't work for as many people.

Comment: After I type 'which python', it shows '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python'. Is this the built-in python? I'm not sure, how to change the python version. Thanks!

Comment: No, that's not the built-in Python, it's another Python 2.7 you've installed in some way. You don't want to "change the python version". You _might_ want to just uninstall that extra Python 2.7 and stick to Apple's, or you might want to keep the extra one. If you have no idea why you might want a second Python 2.7, I'd suggest uninstalling it. (And if you built that second Python 2.7 from source, you may need to rebuild it.)